Flutter How to update Image widget after searching for item in a searchbar widget
I have a search screen that contains a search bar stateful widget. I've already implemented the widget to search a database and select an item.

However now I don't know how to update the SearchImage() to
represent the item I have selected from the SearchBar().

class SearchScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SearchScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Search', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayLarge),
      ),
      body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: const Column(
          children: [
            SearchBar(),
            SearchImage(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Here is the implementation I have for the SearchImage widget:
class SearchImage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SearchImage({super.key});

  @override
  State<SearchImage> createState() => _SearchImageState();
}

class _SearchImageState extends State<SearchImage> {
  late NetworkImage _networkImage;

  void updateImage(String newImageUrl) {
    setState(() {
      _networkImage = NetworkImage(newImageUrl);
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _networkImage = const NetworkImage('placeholder');
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0, left: 25.0, right: 25.0),
        child: Image(
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            image: _networkImage),
      ),
    );
  }
}

How do I call the updateImage method from outside of itself? Does the fact that I am struggling to figure this out mean that this is not the Flutter way of handling state in the application? And if so, how can I modify my SearchScreen to get this behavior to work?
Do I have to convert the SearchScreen into a stateful widget and have some variables to keep track of searchbar selection outside of the controller.text inside SearchBar()?

The idea is the same way Flutter implements TextEditingController to allow you to control TextField widget through controller
Now you need a controller to control SearchImage widget

Create a controller for SearchImage widget

class SearchImageController {
  Function(String newImageUrl)? setNewImage;
}


Require this controller as a param of SearchImage

class SearchImage extends StatefulWidget {
  final SearchImageController controller; // <---- here

  const SearchImage({super.key, required this.controller});

  @override
  State<SearchImage> createState() => _SearchImageState();
}

class _SearchImageState extends State<SearchImage> {
  late NetworkImage _networkImage;

  void updateImage(String newImageUrl) {
    setState(() {
      _networkImage = NetworkImage(newImageUrl);
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _networkImage = const NetworkImage('placeholder');
    widget.controller.setNewImage = updateImage; // <---- here
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {...}
}


Create an instance of this controller in SearchScreen, pass this controller to SearchImage, now you can use this controller to set new image when you want, eg onSubmitted of SearchBar

class SearchScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  SearchScreen({super.key});

  final _searchImageController = SearchImageController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Search', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayLarge),
      ),
      body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SearchBar(
              onSubmitted: (value) {
                _searchImageController.setNewImage?.call(value); // <---- here
              },
            ),
            SearchImage(
              controller: _searchImageController, // <---- here
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


This solution does not seem to work because onSubmitted parameter is not defined in SearchBar and SearchBar is the stateful widget that contains the state of my search bar that holds the selected item.

It's just an example, the focal point here is now you hold the controller, do whatever and whenever you want to update image outside SearchImage widget, to solve your questions:

How do I call the updateImage method from outside of itself?

